# Is it possible to dive having perforation in ears

Tags: health

I have a perforation in my left ear. Is it okay to do scuba diving?
If possible will there be any limitations?

It's a perforation in left outer ear. Small in size.

If scuba diving is not possible with perforated eardrum, what other ways can one go under water that does not let water go inside perforated eardrum ?

Comment: I've never dived, but I think you should get a special medical examination anyway before they let you do it? At least where I live, that's standard, I belive. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitness_to_dive).

Comment: go see an ear specialist.  they deal with a lot of divers and they ought to know.  asking for medical advice here is senseless - you wouldn't know if someone was qualified in giving you an opinion and we don't know what your ear is up to.  I can tell you I visited a specialist after getting a ruptured eardrum and he told me not to dive until it healed.  But that was my ear, not yours.

Answer (score 2):

If the perforation is in your eardrum then the recommendation is not to dive, as you could end up with water in your inner ear that can then easily lead to infection.

I would suggest visiting your local GP.

Comment: Earplugs and scuba diving don't mix. And your local GP probably doesn't know much of anything about scuba diving.

Comment: Thanks Pete. Have edited accordingly. Although your 2nd sentence may not be correct :-)

Comment: Second this.  As a child I had tubes in my ears (in effect, perforated eardrums, except done by the doctor), while they were in I had to avoid immersing my head or subjecting it to any forceful water (say, a shower.)

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately it is up to you what you want to do.  Whilst it may not be recommended it may be possible and testing your equalisation in a public pool that has a 10m dive platform will be the best way for you to figure this out.  I wouldn't just try once either, I would try many times especially when you have congestion or a cold to see how pressure affects your inner ear.  BTW ear plugs are not recommended for diving, there is no such thing as ear plugs for scuba diving